# Power Play: Do I have to collect my weekly bonus every week?

Tags: elite-dangerous

As soon as I have a rating with one of the Powers in Elite Dangerous, I get a weekly credit bonus. What happens if I don't collect that bonus within the week (e.g. when I am on vacation or something)? Do I lose the bonus, or do bonuses accumulate over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just returned from a multi-week exploration trip and found that I can collect 1000 credits only. When I left I believe I was at either rating 2 or 3 which means, had the bonuses accumulated I would have been able to collect more than 500'000 or 50'000 credits.

My conclusion therefore is that bonuses do not accumulate over time and you have to be there every single week to collect, otherwise the credits are wasted.

Comment: My experience back then was the opposite: it was still there after months, and it did accumulate. But it has changed again in May 2016, so a new answer is required.